# POST resquest not accepted while GET is being accepted

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, http, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a http call from angularjs in spring controller and post json data but I am getting this error in angularjs :

```
angular.js:10661 POST http://localhost:8080/shopng/product/add 404 (Not 
Found)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:10661
sendReq @ angular.js:10480
serverRequest @ angular.js:10187
processQueue @ angular.js:14634
(anonymous) @ angular.js:14650
$eval @ angular.js:15916
$digest @ angular.js:15727
$apply @ angular.js:16024
(anonymous) @ angular.js:23416
eventHandler @ angular.js:3293
product_service.js:35 Error while adding product
product_controller.js:30 {productName: "ads", productPrice: 34, description: "ads", imageUrl: "asd"}
```

But when I use GET request then it's not giving me any error but it says media type not supported and when I remove the media type and perform then 'NULL' value is added in database.

Here is my RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductRestController {
@Autowired
ProductDao productDao;
//Add Product

 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product) {
        System.out.println("Creating Product " + product.getProductName());

        if (productDao.isProductExit(product)) {
            System.out.println("A Product with name " + product.getProductName() + " already exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

       productDao.add(product);

       return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Here is my angular's service making request:

```
function addProduct(product){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/shopng/product/add', product)
        .then(
           function(response){
               deferred.resolve(response.data);
           },
           function(errResponse){
               console.log('Error while adding product');
               deferred.reject(errResponse);
           }

        );
    return deferred.promise;
 }
```

here is my github repo of the project : https://github.com/Bk073/Shopping
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your mapping is correct? Can u post your complete controller including the request mapping on the class.

Comment: This question is related to spring boot and not angularjs.

Comment: @IndraneelBende thank you for your response and yes the mapping is correct. I have posted the same question I will share you the link and you may have a look at all the values.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658617/error-while-sending-json-from-angular-to-spring-controller/50659157?noredirect=1#comment88328854_50659157

Comment: @IndraneelBende Thats the same problem only the servlet is different i.e ' localhost:8080/shopng ' in this case and in there it is 'localhost:8080/shopping'

Comment: in that example i dont see where are u adding /shopng or /shopping in the rest controller

Comment: @IndraneelBende do you mind if send the zip of the project ?

Comment: Have you enabled the CSRF?

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne Yes CSRF is enabled and I tried disabling it also.

Comment: I'm assuming that's a typo in the URL's context-root? Your other question has "shoping", this one has "shopng", without the "i".

Comment: have you tried to had headers to your post request on the angular side ?

Comment: @LoïcThierry No I haven't tried using headers on the post request on the angular side. It is giving me data in Json form. Should I have to add headers there ?

Comment: you can try it I don't know if it'll work but I had a similar issu with angular2 so it can work. Angular didn't add the header automatically so it ended up with an error

Comment: @LoïcThierry but i don't think the issue is there. I think the issue is with the controller class

Comment: do you see the output of the prints ? if yes this is not the problem

Comment: No i dont see the output of the print.

Comment: either it's a problem with the headers or the path I look into your project and a didn't see where you add the /shopng to your path (maybe the missing i is the issue too)

Comment: @IndraneelBende now I have added the rest of the code as you have said so there is "/product" mapping in the controller and the shopng is the servlet context

Comment: @LoïcThierry I have added the path in the URI 'http://localhost:8080/shopng/product/add'

Comment: Have you tried this request with POSTMAN or any other client?

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne Yes I have tried and it is giving me 404 error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your securityconfig class.

Please disable the csrf as below.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
    .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
    .usernameParameter("username")
    .passwordParameter("password")  
    .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .and().csrf().disable();
    //.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
```

You are getting 404 - because the csrf check is throwing an exception. To handle that exception, you have not added an exception handler. So the  404 means - exception handler is not found, not the post request itself.

If you need to secure with csrf, keep in mind to send csrf token with the request.

Please see the below attachment with successful response.

[image]

updated code https://github.com/supun/Shopping

Comment: Thank you so much it had taken my 3 days and now it's working

Answer (score 0):

The **value** property in your controller is incorrect. It should start with **/** . Please change to  **/add** in your controller

```
//Add Product

 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product) {
        System.out.println("Creating Product " + product.getProductName());

        if (productDao.isProductExit(product)) {
            System.out.println("A Product with name " + product.getProductName() + " already exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

       productDao.add(product);

       return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Add RequestBody instead of ModelAttribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createProduct(@RequestBody  Product product) {
        System.out.println("Creating Product " + product.getProductName());

        if (productDao.isProductExit(product)) {
            System.out.println("A Product with name " + product.getProductName() + " already exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

       productDao.add(product);

       return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: I have changed to that also.